# Where's the edges of the zones?

Tags: sunset-overdrive

I need to figure out which High Points are in which zone, but the edges of the zones aren't clear, since the line on the map where the Tokyo District's name appears when entering from the Harbor District isn't the same line where the Harbor District's name appears when entering from the Tokyo District.

So, is there a clear map of where each zone starts and ends?